# Why is my picture link extending beneath the image?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm working on a photo page for a site I'm creating, however it seems that the link is extending into the whitespace beneath the image. The problem disappears when I remove the surrounding `<section>` but I'm not sure why.

Here's a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Supergogoman/9t4yn8gy/1/) better showcasing my code and the problem

```css
.photo {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.photo a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.photo img {
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<section class="photo">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://upshout.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dwarf-kitten-01.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://upshout.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dwarf-kitten-01.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://upshout.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dwarf-kitten-01.jpg" />
  </a>
</section>
```

I added a `border` to the problem area. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: float: left is making it... try add display: block; to the .photo a {} part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `a` and `img` are inline elements, so

- make `a` a block level element by `display:block`, to the `border` appear around the image
- set `display:block` to `img` to remove underneath whitespace caused by being an inline element. *(other solution would be setting `vertical-align-bottom`, given `img` by default is `vertical-align:baseline`)*

**Note:**  I gave the `img` a `max-width:100%` to be responsive, and if you give the `border` to `img` instead of `a`, the `a` being `display:block` isn't necessary anymore, although is good to have it.

See more about inline elements [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes) on w3

```css
.photo {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.photo a {
  display: block;
}
.photo img {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 1%
}
```

```html
<section class="photo">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://upshout.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dwarf-kitten-01.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://upshout.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dwarf-kitten-01.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://upshout.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dwarf-kitten-01.jpg" />
  </a>
</section>
```